# Chain rule of an abstract function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am reading my notes of the course on calculus in several variables, and appear the following statement.

I we consider the function $U(f(t),t)$, then
$$
\frac{\partial U(f(t),t)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial U(f(t),t)}{\partial t} + U(f(t),t) \frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial t}.  
$$

**Is it correct ?**

*Every time that I tried to manipulate a function in an abstract form, finally I can no obtain the partial derivates. Somebody can help me, please.*

Comment: Your last edit has made your expression incorect. Notice how $$ \frac{\partial U(f(t),t)}{\partial t}$$ is now on both sides of the equality.

Comment: @Digitallis that is my question, because, I don't understand if it is correct or not ? do you know what is the correct partial derivative of $$\frac{\partial U(f(t),t)}{\partial t}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing partial derivatives and derivatives.

Here's how you can avoid these mistakes.

In this exercise you are asked to calculate the derivative of  a composition of functions namely the function $U$ and the function $\gamma : t \rightarrow (f(t),t).$ To compute the derivative you will therefore use the chain rule

$$ \frac{d(U\circ\gamma)}{dt} = \frac{d U}{d\gamma} \frac{d\gamma }{dt}.$$

While doing this the partial derivatives of $U$ will appear. To avoid ambiguity we need to name the variables which $U$ uses as an input.

Let $U : \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R: (x,y) \rightarrow U(x,y).$ This enables us to write down the partial derivatives of U as $\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}$.

The derivative of $U \circ \gamma$ is therefore

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \big( U(f(t),t) \big) = \frac{\partial U}{\partial x}(f(t),t) \cdot \frac{df}{dt} + \frac{\partial U}{\partial y} (f(t),t) \cdot \frac{dt}{dt}$$

Here the expression $\frac{\partial U}{\partial y} (f(t),t)$ means "the partial derivative of $U$ with respect to $y$ evaluated at the point $(f(t),t)$". You could rewrite this as

$$ \frac{\partial U(x,y)}{\partial y}_{\Big\vert_{\Large{(f(t),t)}}}$$

Comment: Thanks, now is more clear for me !